# Open a cloned git repo having local changes on a remote machine with a Git GUI client

Tags: linux, git, user-interface, ssh

I have a Linux virtual machine that:

1. is SSH reachable
2. doesn't have GUI
3. has cloned Git repo with local changes on it

I am currently remotely working on it through SSH-enabled VS Code. While I can use the integrated Git support and/or plug-ins so that to easily do all Git operations I would still like to use a dedicated Git GUI client for that purpose.

How could I connect to / open a remotely cloned Git repo (not by creating a Git server) with any of the well-known Git GUI clients - SmartGit, SourceTree, etc.? I presume it should be again over SSH. I know those clients could clone a Git repo through SSH but can they open such through SSH?

Comment: You can just ssh into the virtual machine and use Git from the command line there. Your life will be easier if you learn how to do this without GUI, you will need it again sooner or later.

Comment: I know this, but I don't want the hassle and hence the question. Git GUI clients are far more convenient. I don't want to become cmd Git guru but to do my work in an efficient way.

Comment: Voting to close: seeking recommendations for tools.

Comment: @jthill didn't understand you fully - you want to see tool recommendations so that to close the topic?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393489/we-don-t-allow-questions-seeking-recommendations-for-books-tools-software-lib

Comment: I tested SourceTree, GitKraken neither support SSH tunnelling to open projects. I use a Mac and my projects are located in a ubuntu VM